# WPF - Bind a textbox's content other Textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have two text box which are working independently in a wpf mvvm. But now i want to bind input of one textbox to other text box on basis of a check box.

```
  <Label Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" Style="{StaticResource StlLblForm}" Margin="0,5">First Name:</Label>
  <TextBox Grid.Row="4" MaxLength="10" Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource StlTxtForm}" Text="{Binding FirstName}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="0,1,0,11" />

  <Label  Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="0" Style="{StaticResource StlLblForm}" Margin="0,5">Last Name:</Label>
  <TextBox Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource StlTxtForm}" Text="{Binding LastName}" AcceptsReturn="True" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="0,1,0,11" />
  <CheckBox Content="CopyFirstNameToLast" />
```

So when i check the check box it repliates the First Name to Last Name. Can i do this without code behind. If yes then how ?

Comment: You need onproperty changed notification

Comment: It's simple to bind last name to first name in the XAML, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9586956/how-to-bind-a-controls-property-to-another-controls-property for more info.  However the check box makes it more complicated, you may have to write a value converter to get this work.

Comment: Something like this perhaps? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23225751/wpf-binding-to-two-properties

Comment: Any reason why you would prefer to avoid code behind? You could do with a custom converter but code-behind for your scenario would be the proper approach IMHO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without code:

```
 <Label>First Name:</Label>
 <TextBox x:Name="txtFirstName" Width="100" MaxLength="10" Text="{Binding FirstName}" />
<Label >Last Name:</Label>
  <TextBox Width="100">
     <TextBox.Style>
                <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                    <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding LastName}" />
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=chk, Path=IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding ElementName=txtFirstName, Path=Text, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </TextBox.Style>
        </TextBox>
        <CheckBox x:Name="chk" Content="CopyFirstNameToLast" />
```

Comment: works like a charm. thank you so much. that's what i was searching for :)

Answer (score 2):

As you are following MVVM pattern to implement your application, you should notice that according to [MVVM pattern guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848246.aspx) the view should **not** contain any application logic:

> The view is responsible for defining the structure, layout, and
>   appearance of what the user sees on the screen. Ideally, the view is
>   defined purely with XAML, with a limited code-behind that does not
>   contain business logic.

Replicating your `FirstName` to `LastName` **is** a part of your application logic, so you should delegate this task to your ViewModel.

Quoting MSDN again:

> The view model acts as an intermediary between the view and the model,
>   and is responsible for handling the view logic.

which is exactly what you are trying to achieve.

So to keep things tidy, your should define `FirstName` and `LastName` properties in your ViewModel which will be bound to View's TextBoxes, just like you do in the code in your question:

```
// ViewModel
public const string FirstNamePropertyName = "FirstName";
private string _firstName = null;
public string FirstName
{
    get
    {
        return _firstName;
    }

    set
    {
        _firstName = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(FirstNamePropertyName);
    }
}

public const string LastNamePropertyName = "LastName";
private string _lastName = null;
public string LastName
{
    get
    {
        return _lastName;
    }

    set
    {
        _lastName = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(LastNamePropertyName);
    }
}

<!-- XAML -->

<Label Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" Style="{StaticResource StlLblForm}" Margin="0,5">First Name:</Label>
<TextBox Grid.Row="4" MaxLength="10" Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource StlTxtForm}" Text="{Binding FirstName}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="0,1,0,11" />

<Label  Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="0" Style="{StaticResource StlLblForm}" Margin="0,5">Last Name:</Label>
<TextBox Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource StlTxtForm}" Text="{Binding LastName}" AcceptsReturn="True" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="0,1,0,11" />
```

While the CheckBox can be handled in two ways:

- you bind its `Checked` event to a ViewModel's command where you
  manipulate your `FirstName` and `LastName` properties and you pass to it checkbox's `IsChecked` property value as command parameter (hard way)
- you bind `IsChecked` property to the ViewModel's boolean property and
  handle your logic in its setter (easy way)

So to do this the easy way:

```
// ViewModel
public const string CheckedPropertyName = "Checked";
private bool _checked = false;
public bool Checked
{
    get
    {
        return _checked;
    }

    set
    {
        _checked = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(CheckedPropertyName);

        // app logic is handled here
        if (_checked)
        {
            LastName = FirstName;
        }
    }
}

<!-- XAML -->
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Checked}" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But I am using Bindablebase which gives error that RaisePropertyChanged is not defined.

Comment: You should use `BindableBase.SetProperty` then: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn736263(v=pandp.50).aspx